# Locking cells and replacing content with data validation/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

E5 is a dropdown with the following 3 options: None, Self-Consumption, Overnight Charging

1. When 'none' is selected, the content in cells F37, F41:H41, F50:H51 needs to be cleared and the cells locked.
2. When 'self-consumption' is selected, F37 needs to be unlocked, and F41:H41, F50:H51 need to be cleared and locked.
3. When 'overnight-charging' is selected, F37 needs to be cleared and locked, and F41:H41, F50:H51 need to be unlocked.

E4 is a checkbox and when this is unchecked the following cells need to be cleared and locked:
F25:J25, F26, F28:J29, F31:J31.

I've saved the following macros to clear and lock the cells. Please can someone let me know what I do next to add the conditions as above. Many thanks.

```
Sub Solar()
'
' Solar Macro
' clear and lock cells if no panels being installed
'

'
    Range("F25:J25,F26,F28:J29,F31:J31").Select
    Range("F31").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
End Sub
Sub Battery_SC()
'
' Battery_SC Macro
' Clear and lock cell if no self-consumption battery being installed
'

'
    Range("F37").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0%"
    Range("F37").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
End Sub

Sub Battery_OC()
'
' Battery_OC
' Clear and lock cells if no overnight battery being installed
'

'
    Range("F41:H41,F50:H50,F51:H51").Select
    Range("F51").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$5" Then
        If Target.Value = "None" Then
            Range("F37,F41:H41,F50:H50,F51:H51").Select
            Range("F51").Activate
            Selection.ClearContents
            Selection.Locked = True
            Selection.FormulaHidden = False
        End If
        If Target.Value = "Self-Consumption" Then
            Range("F41:H41,F50:H50,F51:H51").Select
            Range("F51").Activate
            Selection.ClearContents
            Selection.Locked = True
            Selection.FormulaHidden = False
        End If
        If Target.Value = "Overnight Charging" Then
            Range("F37").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Selection.Locked = True
            Selection.FormulaHidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: HAve you tried recoding a mcro doing the first steps you need your formula to do?

Comment: What did you try by your own?

Comment: I've tried using data validation and formulas but couldn't come up with a solution. I've never used macros/VBA before so am unsure what to do - is this the best way to solve? Thank you

Comment: I've figured out the macros and updated the original post. I hope I've done it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a "Worksheet Change" event.  When something changes in a specified cell, known as the "Target, then do something.  This is the outline, you would need to fill in the "Do Something" parts.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$5" Then
        If Target.Value = "None" Then
            Cells(1, 1) = 1
        End If
        If Target.Value = "Self-Consumption" Then
            Cells(1, 1) = 2
        End If
        If Target.Value = "Overnight Charging" Then
            Cells(1, 1) = 3
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

@Darrell - Is this wrong?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$5" Then
    If Target.Value = "None" Then
        With Range("F37,F41:H41,F50:H50,F51:H51")
             .ClearContents
             .Locked = True
             .FormulaHidden = False
        End With
    End If
    If Target.Value = "Self-Consumption" Then
        With Range("F41:H41,F50:H50,F51:H51")
             .ClearContents
             .Locked = True
             .FormulaHidden = False
        End With
    End If
    If Target.Value = "Overnight Charging" Then
        With Range("F37")
             .ClearContents
             .Locked = True
             .FormulaHidden = False
        End With
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you Darrell, I'll have a go at adding this. Please can I just ask where do I put this code? Do I leave it as a module or do I need to put it under the correct sheet?

Comment: It needs to be in the correct sheet.  Won't work in a module.

Comment: I'm afraid I may have misunderstood this for the line - the line < Cells(1, 1) = 1 >
I've put as above:

Comment: That was just a filler to populate A1 with a 1,2, or 3 based on the selection.  That was the "Do Something".  You can replace each of those with the actions you want to happen with each selection.

Comment: So should the code I've put at the bottom of my original post work, or have I got it wrong? Sorry if I'm being really daft.

Comment: Ideally you should avoid `Activate` and `Select`.  I edited.

Comment: Fabulous, thank you - one more question, how do I save it/make it work? I clicked the save button but the cells don't seem to be locked. Do I need to add further code somewhere to link it?

Comment: This assumes your validation is in E5.  When that cell changes you should see a change.  Saving the file with an .xlsm extension makes it a macro-enabled file.

Comment: Ah the target cell is E5:F5 (merged) could this be the problem? I've tried inputting Target.Address = "$E$5:$F$5" and... Range("$E$5:$F$5") but they don't work - how would I input a range for the target?

Comment: Your using data validation?  If you unmerge, is the content in E5 or F5?  If F5, then use that as the target.  I have tested with merged cells.  The content has to be in one or the other.

Comment: I've removed the data validation and unmerged the target cell and data is now in F5. The cells content is clearing when changing the selection but they aren't locking?

Comment: Locking only takes effect when you protect the sheet.  That is another step.

Comment: Once I lock the sheet all the other cells (not including the ones the code is for) are locked and the cells the code is for are unlocked and they remain so when I'm changing the selection in F5, which should lock them. I've tried locking them by formatting the cells but when I do that they remain locked when F5 changes?

Comment: If you want only those cells to be locked, you can select the entire sheet and then under "Format cells" you uncheck locked.  Then only the ones you designated as locked will be unavailable after you lock.  Then you unprotect to modify the locked cells and protect lock them after you modify.  You can research protecting sheets in VBA.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted to close out